# REGO how to get object (map) keys that match a pattern

Tags: kubernetes, opa, open-policy-agent, rego

Working with [Rego](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/), the [Open Policy Agent](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/) (OPA) "rules" language, and given the following data:

```
{
    "x-foo": "a",
    "x-bar": "b",
    "y-foo": "c",
    "y-bar": "d"
}
```

what is the correct Rego expression(s) or statement(s) to get just the keys that start with "x-"? That is, I want an array of

```
[ "x-foo", "x-bar" ]
```

I know about the `startswith()` function, and I've tried various attempts at [comprehensions](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/#comprehensions), but no matter what I try I can't get it to work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished either by using a comprehension, like you suggest, or a partial rule that [generates a set](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/#generating-sets):

```
x_foo_comprehension := [key | object[key]; startswith(key, "x-")]

x_foo_rule[key] {
    object[key]
    startswith(key, "x-")
}
```

Finally, if you need to take nested keys into account, you could use the walk built-in to traverse the object:

```
x_foo_rule[key] {
    walk(object, [path, value])
    last := path[count(path) - 1]
    startswith(last, "x-")
    key := concat(".", path)
}

# x_foo_rule == {
#     "x-bar",
#     "x-foo",
#     "y-bar.x-bar",
#     "y-bar.x-foo"
# ]
```

Comment: Thanks, Devoops, that got me enough of an answer that I was able to solve my full problem.

Comment: Great! You can mark the answer as accepted :)